fread column with only NA values as POSIXct returns warning and a character column
Update:
I have opened an issue for this: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/6208

I would like to read a column of a NA values as POSIXct using fread.
I would expect this to work:
library(data.table)
fwrite(data.table(datetime = as.POSIXct(NA)), "test.csv")
fread("test.csv", colClasses = "POSIXct")

However, this gives the following warning:
Warning message:
Column 'datetime' was requested to be 'POSIXct' but fread encountered the following error:
    character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
so the column has been left as type 'character' 

In contrast using utils::write.csv and utils::read.csv this works:
write.csv(data.frame(datetime = as.POSIXct(NA)), "test.csv", row.names = FALSE)
read.csv("test.csv", colClasses = "POSIXct")

Is there a possible workaround?
I used data.table_1.15.4.

This might be more relevant at https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues

Problem might be that we can do \class<-`(NA, 'POSICct')but there's no such thing likeNA_POSIXct_`.

@zx8754 I will open an issue - thanks for the idea.

a work around is to have fread always read it as double/numeric, and convert to posixct after.
library(data.table)
fwrite(data.table(datetime = as.POSIXct(NA)), "test.csv")
dt_in <- fread("test.csv", colClasses = "double")[, datetime := as.POSIXct(datetime, origin="1970-01-01")]
dt_in


Thanks for that workaround. I will keep the question open for now, otherwise I will accept your answer later.
